# Generate Automated Google Analytics PDF Reports

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My company uses Google Analytics for website tracking.  Every two weeks, we export 10 different reports to PDF showing the last two weeks of tracking data for various subdirectories of our website.  Right now, this is a manual process, i.e. somebody has to pull up each page in GA and go to Export -> PDF.

I would very much like to automate this process.  I've looked at various solutions with no result.

1. We can create a scheduled email in GA, but the only frequencies are Daily, Weekly, Monthly, and Quarterly.  I need once every two weeks.
2. We can use the Google Analytics API, but the API seems mostly designed for generating custom queries and returning strings with the query results.  There's nothing in the API that allows me to a) export a page to a PDF or b) simply copy a page as-is to a Google Doc, where I can then export it.  I don't need any custom formatting of the data: we're happy with the GA display as-is.

Is there a way in GA to create an automated process that simply exports pages to PDF with a custom frequency?  I appreciate any assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use the magic script to setup reports in google spreadsheets - https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/report-automation-magic

2) In the script editor, create a two, time-based month triggers (on the 1st & on the 15th) to run getData (this is a function in the magic script that...gets the data).

3) Use my function getURLandEmail, to email yourself when the reports are ready - http://www.swellpath.com/2013/04/google-analytics-report-automation/

4) Receive the run report and download it as PDF and send to colleagues. *I've tried searching/developing a way for Google Spreadsheets to export the pdf and send it to my email, but I don't believe it has the functionality of sending pdfs.

Feel free to ask questions, Nick

Comment: I'm aware of Magic Script, but this seems mostly useful for exporting rows of numerical data from Analytics to Google Spreadsheets.  I want to get not just the data but all of the charts and graphs that are on the Analytics pages we've been printing up.  I don't want to have to recreate the visuals for each report in Spreadsheets.  Heck, I don't want to have to recreate the organization of data in each report.  I'd rather just say, "Hey Analytics, send me the Content Drilldown overview page as a PDF twice a month".

Comment: If you really wanted to you could recreate the dashboards, etc using Google Spreadsheets, but that's not what you want to do. Couldn't you just set up two monthly reports? One that would fire on the first and another on the 15th.

Comment: I could, but each report would give me all data for the past month since the date of the report, not for the past two weeks.  In addition, I need the reports every other Tuesday, which fall on different days of the month each month.